Ubuntu 24.04 on Vmware Workstaion Pro 17 not copying and pasting between host and VM
First thing first heres everything I'm running:
Host-Windows 11 NVIDIA 1060 AMD 5600
VM - Ubuntu 24.04
Virtualisation- Vmware Workstation 17.5.2
The problem I'm having is that Ubuntu and Windows will not allow the copying and pasting of files across systems. I've tried drag and drop, through right click, keyboard shortcuts. The systems will not connect.
I have setup a shared folder in the vmware interface but it doesn't show up.(Picture)
I have had to bridge the network connection because NAT won't work either.
I have checked to make sure Guest Isolation has the drag and drop and copy and paste features enabled (Picture)
No USB's plugged into the host machine will prompt to be connected to the VM either and that setting is also enabled.
The version of Vmware had Ubuntu 22.04 installed on it and the drag and drop worked along with the copy and paste of files. I have noidea why it wont work with this version.
There was a problem with the login page it went black nad unresponsive I think it has something to do with my NVIDIA graphics card and I had to turn off Accelerate 3D Graphics in the display section to get the GUI to load (It would still run cmd line without the setting changed)
enter image description here

I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve the issue?

have you tried to install:
sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop -y

or
sudo apt install open-vm-tools-* -y

or try to edit your .vmx file by adding
keyboard.allowBothIRQs = "FALSE"
keyboard.vsub.enable = "TRUE"

